# URI with multiple URL formats (after slug)

Tags: sections, routes

Is it possible to have a URI like this: /artist/{slug}/news
to create an overview of all news articles of this particular artist?

I tried to set it up with Routes and with a section Entry URI, but I get a 404

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by [writing a module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html) and using the `UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` event.

Basic example:

```php
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent;
use craft\web\UrlManager;
use yii\base\Event;

class CustomModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
            static function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
                $artistEntries = Entry::find()->section('artists')->all();

                foreach ($artistEntries as $artistEntry) {
                    $event->rules[$artistEntry->uri] = ['template' => '_pages/artists/news'];
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then, in the _*pages/artists/news.twig* template, you'll need to extract the artist's slug from `craft.app.request.url` and use it to get the Entry corresponding to your artist.

Comment: Thanks very much!